# Displaying nonLatin characters

Tags: utf-8, coldfusion, include

I'm working on a website that's going to have some non-Latin text/Latin text with accents on it. I set the character encoding to UTF-8, and that works for Spanish, but only if I use the html name for the character: ie, &ntilde instead of just ñ.

Eventually, though, I plan to add text in a totally different script, and I'd prefer to avoid having to type the html name for each letter. Is there a way I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

Sure. What you have at the moment is probably one of these:

- You edit the text file as UTF-8, but you forgot to let the server tell that to your clients and did not include a character set statement in the file itself.

  - First element in head: `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`
  - Search in your servers documentation for content-type.
- You edit the file as some non-Unicode character set, but the clients think it is UTF-8. Open it in the editor of your choice and re-save as UTF-8.

Comment: I added the tag you gave and checked the file's encoding type, but it's still not displaying properly. If it helps, here's the [link](http://dcwebdev.net/langlearn/).

Comment: Looks like you had an interesting encoding experience there. Parts of that file were: Saved as UTF-8 => Interpreted as Windows Codepage whatever => Saved as UTF-8. Just open the file as UTF-8, replace all bad parts and resave as UTF-8. That should work.

Comment: I'm guessing that's because the main file has two other files included to it. I tried adding <cfprocessingdirective pageEncoding="utf-8">, as suggested in the other question (both with and without the <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> also present), but for some reason that moved everything out of the <head> and put it at the start of the body.